# Error when converting a linked list into an array of pointers

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

This is the program prompt:

Write a C++ program to process periodic table information from a file. Each element will have an atomic number, a name, an abbreviation, and a mass. Your program must include:

1. An Element structure to be defined in a header file: Element.h
2. A function read_table that will return the number of elements read from the file and via a reference parameter, a pointer to an array of pointers to the elements read. The data file is located at /user/tvnguyen7/data/periodictable.dat. This function must read in the data by constructing a linked list and convert the linked list into an array of pointers. The prototype for this function is to be included in the Element.h file. The function will return 0 on any error condition.
3. A main program that will call read_table to read in the table, sort the table using the element name and print out the table using the required output format. You can use qsort in cstdlib or write your own sort function.
4. Dynamic memory must be allocated and deallocated properly.

This is what I have for periodic_table.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include "Element.h"
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int count = 0;
    Element **pt = new Element *[count];

    cout << setw(30) << left << " Periodic Table by K. Nguyen" << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << setw(30) << " Number of elements: " << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << setw(5) << " Name" << right << setw(20) << "Abr" << setw(5) << " ANo" << setw(8) << "Mass" << endl;
    cout << setw(20) << left << " --------------------" << setw(4) << right << "---" << setw(5) << "----" << setw(8) << "-------" << endl;

    read_table(&count, pt);  

    delete [] pt;
    return 0;
}
```

Here's what I have for read_table.cpp:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Element.h"

using namespace std;

int read_table(int *count, Element **ppt){

struct Node {
    Element *pElement;
    Node *next;
};

int temp = 0;

int aNum;
string aBr;
double mass;
string name;

Node *n = nullptr;
Node *h = nullptr;
Node *t = nullptr;

ifstream infile;
infile.open("periodictable.dat");

while(infile >> aNum >> aBr >> mass >> name){
    Element *e = new Element;
    e->ANo = aNum;
    e->Abr = aBr;
    e->Mass = mass;
    e->Name = name;

    n = new Node;
    n->pElement = e;
    n->next = nullptr;

    if(h == nullptr){
        h = t = n;
    }
    else {
        t->next = n;
        t = n;
    }

    temp++;
}
infile.close();

int i = 0;
for(Node *x = h; x, i < temp; x = x->next, i++){
    ppt[i] = x->pElement;
}

*count = temp;
return 0;
}
```

Here's what I have for Element.h:

```
#ifndef ELEMENT_H
#define ELEMENT_H

using namespace std;

struct Element {
    int ANo;
    string Abr;
    double Mass;
    string Name;
};

int read_table(int *count, Element **ppt);

#endif
```

I think the problem is in this for loop in read_table.cpp:

```
int i = 0;
for(Node *x = h; x, i < temp; x = x->next, i++){
    ppt[i] = x->pElement;
}
```

and also I am not sure if I am passing in the array of pointers right or not (this is in periodic_table.cpp):

```
int count = 0;
Element **pt = new Element *[count];
....
read_table(&count, pt);
```

The error is:
In function 'main': periodic_table.cpp: undefined reference to 'read_table(int*, Element**)'

My program cannot run when I include that for loop; however, it runs fine without it so I think I am doing something wrong there but I don't know what. Please help.

Comment: You haven't adequately described the problem you are trying to solve. If you are getting an error, what is the error message? Are you getting an error when compiling or when running? If you don't get an error, how does your program's behavior differ from the behavior you expect?

Comment: Consider using standard containers instead of writing your own linked list. It would greatly simplify the task.

Comment: Your requirement of using qsort is not going to work.  Your Element contains `std::string` members, and you can't use qsort on those entities.  Use `std::sort` instead.  Now I wonder how competent the teacher is wrt C++.

Comment: This seems like a horribly designed assignment...why read into a linked list and then convert it into an array of pointers? What benefit does that give you?

Comment: So the error said: In function 'main': undefined reference to 'read_table(int*, Element**)'

Comment: This is basically a C assignment with a couple of C++ keywords thrown in.

Comment: `int count = 0; **pt = new Element *[count];` means that `pt` will _always_ point to an empty array of pointers, no matter how `count` changes thereafter. This assignment description reads like C and not C++, which is damaging to anyone trying to learn modern, practical C++. You would gain a lot and spare many headaches if you used `std::vector` instead of pointer arrays, `std::sort` instead of `qsort`, and stopped using `new`/`delete` altogether

Comment: The thing is my professor wants us to learn pointers and array in C++ through this project, and he specifically said not to use vectors.

Comment: this is a linker error, please show how you are compiling and linking your program

Comment: @Allen Another waste of time project.   If the goal is to teach proper memory management, the assignment should be to create your own vector class instead of these pointer gymnastics that no one uses.   Also, it isn't assuring that the professor didn't know that qsort will not work for a class such as `Element`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Why won't `qsort` work with `Element`s and `std::string`s?

Comment: we can debate whether or not we like the assignment. OP has to do what he is told. We should answer his actual problem - which is that he is not linking main.cpp and read_file.cpp

Comment: so Allen - please show how you are compiling and linking. YOur problem is that you have two separate cpp files that need to be linked together. We dont know what tools or pltform you are using so cannot tell you how to do that

Comment: or - you can get rid of read_table.cpp and put that code in main.cpp

Comment: Hi pm100, so I am using Putty to connect to the school's Linux server to run the main file. I have all three files saved in the same folder. I try to use g++ periodic_table.cpp then it gives me the undefined reference error. The thing is the professor wants to have a separate read_table.cpp file for read table function.

Comment: Oh I think I know why it doesn't work on the school server. It's because the periodictable.dat is local and not on the server. However, when I try to run the program on my computer using NetBeans, the .dat file is in the local folder and it said "Run failed"

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit [See Notes](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/qsort)

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie An `Element*` seems pretty trivial to me. Perhaps rescind your scathing aspersions as to the professor's competence, because there's nothing wrong with the qsort requirement.

Comment: Ok, the sort is on pointers.  But I can't forgive even mentioning qsort in a supposed C++ course.

Comment: This is what I translated the situation as, "The thing is my professor wants us to not learn C++ through this project, and he specifically said not to use idiomatic C++."

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Microsoft Visual Studio(The one I use the most for C++); go on Solution explorer; copy the path for read_table.cpp; right click on Source Files folder in the explorer, add existing item. Then paste the path on to it. Click OK then run your program again. It should work.